# How to differentiate between relations in Octobercms Backend Form

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, octobercms

I have a model which has multiple one to many relations within it. I would like to enable functionality so that when a specific relation is created onRelationManageCreate, code is executed but not when the other relations are created.

Example:

When an invoice is created through relation widget no extra code is executed.

When a delivery is created through relation widget extra code is executed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the related [Model's Events](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events) to accomplish this. You would add either a beforeCreate() or afterCreate() method to the delivery model and execute your code there.

Something to note is this code would get called every time a new delivery is created (not just through the relation manager).